# Use external function to fill text in Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm creating a sign-up form using Google forms for a summer camp for kids. The price for each kid depends on multiple factors such as whether there's a sibling going as well, if the kid plays in a specific team, if he has four arms and so on.
I want to show the price depending on those factors (each is asked earlier in the form). Is there a more elegant way to do so using an external function? It could be a Google script that receives the answers given so far and returns the `int` representing such price. The quick-and-dirty solution is to use multiple pages and redirect the user based on the answers but it's not very nice nor tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1 Google Form to do so which everyone will use. The following is just an example of how I would do that.

**The Form**

[image]

**And the Code**

```
function myFunction() {
   // get all of the answers
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var data = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      var record = {};

      record.question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
      record.answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
      data.push(record);
    }
  }

  // check if there was response
  if (data.length == 0)
    return

  // calculate cost based on the provided factors
  var numberOfSibling = Number(data[1].answer)

  var team = data[2].answer
  var teamCost = 1;
  if (team == 'team1')
    teamCost = 1;
  if (team == 'team2')
    teamCost = 2;
  if (team == 'team3')
    teamCost = 3;


  var fourEyesExists  = data[3].answer
  var fourEyesCost
  if (fourEyesExists == "Yes" )
    fourEyesCost = 4;
  else 
    fourEyesCost = 1;

  var cost =  25*numberOfSibling+(teamCost*2)+(fourEyesCost*12);
  // Show the price to the kid
  form.setConfirmationMessage('You are going to ask you dad to pay: $' + cost + '. May god be with you son. If your dad refused, offer to clean the dishes for: ' + cost/2 + ' days.');


  // delete the response
  form.deleteAllResponses();

}
```

When Submit is clicked, the price will show up.